# ansible iterate over only one type of elements in dictionary

Tags: ansible

I have vars defined like this:

```
x_named_zones:
  - name: 'example1.com'
    type: 'dynamic'
  - name: 'example2.org'
    type: 'dynamic'
  - name: 'example3.tld'
    type: 'master'
```

and I would like to iterate over them with a task:

```
- name: loop over the list
  debug:
    msg: 'name: {{ item.name }} type: {{ item.type }}'
  loop: '{{ x_named_zones }}'
```

and this works. But how can I loop over the list where the `type: dynamic` only? So the expected result of the loop task would be:

`example1.com` and `example2.org`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the items you want

```yaml
- name: loop over the list
  debug:
    msg: "name: {{ item.name }} type: {{ item.type }}"
  loop: "{{ x_named_zones|selectattr('type', 'eq', 'dynamic') }}"
```

---

Notes

- The iteration will fail if the atribute *type* is missing in any of the items. For example, iteration of the data below

```yaml
    x_named_zones:
      - name: 'example1.com'
        type: 'dynamic'
      - name: 'example2.org'
        type: 'dynamic'
      - name: 'example3.tld'
        type: 'master'
      - name: 'example4.tld'
        misc: 'master backup'
```

will fail

```yaml
TASK [loop over the list] *************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => 
  msg: '''dict object'' has no attribute ''type'''
```

In this case, you can use the filter *json_query*. This filter ignores missing attributes. For example,

```yaml
    - name: loop over the list
      debug:
        msg: "name: {{ item.name }} type: {{ item.type }}"
      loop: "{{ x_named_zones|json_query('[?type == `dynamic`]') }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
msg: 'name: example1.com type: dynamic'
msg: 'name: example2.org type: dynamic'
```

- Update the items of the list with default *type* if you are not able, or don't want to use *json_query*. For example,

```yaml
default_type: 'static'
x_named_zones_update: "{{ [{'type': default_type}]|
                          product(x_named_zones)|
                          map('combine')|
                          list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
x_named_zones_update:
  - name: example1.com
    type: dynamic
  - name: example2.org
    type: dynamic
  - name: example3.tld
    type: master
  - misc: master backup
    name: example4.tld
    type: static
```

Comment: Single quotes after loop changed to double quotes and now it is working, thank you! Very good solution because ```type: dynamic``` not exists in variables, it will just skip the task and not throwing error.

Comment: Right. I fixed the code. Thank you. I added examples on how to handle missing attributes.